# Android - Stream doesn't read array properly

Tags: java, android, stream, cryptography

I'm currently working on a connection between my Raspberry Pi and my Android device. 
This connection is encrypted with blowfish and seems to work fine with smaller sizes (usually below 1 kB). In a next step I tried to send a picture from my Pi to my device which should be encrypted aswell. My device throws me the exception `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted` and after a bit of debugging I discovered that about 90% of the data transmitted is set to zero (tested with an array with the size 2444368, after position 212536 everything is zero).

My first guess was that Android can't allocate enough memory for my array but as there was no exception telling me so and after I told Android that my app uses much ram via `largeHeap=true` that wasn't is question anymore. It might be that I do not know enough about how Android works so I'd like to ask you to help me with it. The parts in question (EncryptionUtil not shown, it's not part of the problem):

Client side:

```
    public final byte[] readWithAppend() throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException{
    byte[] b = new byte[read()]; //works fine, tells me the size of the array
    System.out.println("Trying to read an array with the size " + b.length);
    in.read(b,0,b.length);//No Exception here, so allocation works
    if(b.length >= 10000){ //Just some debug for me to compare both sides, server and client.
        File f;
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f = new File(debugFile,EncryptionUtil.randomString(80)));
        System.out.println("PATH: " + f);
        out.write(b);out.close();
    }
    System.out.println("After position " + searchPos(b) + " everything is 0 ?!?!?");
    b = EncryptionUtil.decrypt(enc, b, sessionKey); //The Exception gets thrown here.
    return b;
}

private int searchPos(byte[] b){
    int pos = b.length;
    for(int i = b.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
        if(b[i] != 0)return pos;
        else pos--;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Serverside:

```
    private final void write(byte[] b,int off,int len,boolean appendLength) throws IOException{
    try {
        byte[] b2;
        if(len != b.length || off != 0){ //Just ignore this case
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len-off];System.arraycopy(b, off, buffer, 0, len);
            b2 = EncryptionUtil.encrypt(enc, buffer, sessionKey);
        }else{ //This is the case we have to look at
            b2 = EncryptionUtil.encrypt(enc, b, sessionKey);
            System.out.println("Sending an array with the size " + b2.length);
            System.out.println("Decrypting to check for mistakes");
            EncryptionUtil.decrypt(SymmetricEncryption.Blowfish, b2, sessionKey); //Debug.
            if(b2.length >= 10000){ //Again, debug to compare the both files
                FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(new File("serverFile"));
                out2.write(b2);out2.close();
            }
        }
        if(appendLength)write(b2.length); //Works as well
        System.out.println("Length: " + b2.length + "; only writing: " + ((int)len/b.length)*b2.length);// it writes everything.
        out.write(b2,0,((int)len/b.length)*b2.length);  //The flush part happens somewhere else.
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException| NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException| BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I know that it takes some time to work into my code but I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Edit:
Code regarding the EncryptionUtil

```
  public static final byte[] encrypt(final SymmetricEncryption enc,final byte[] content,final SecretKey key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
      final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(enc.toString());
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
      return cipher.doFinal(content);
  }

  public static final byte[] decrypt(final SymmetricEncryption enc,final byte[] text,final SecretKey key) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
      final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(enc.toString());
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
      return cipher.doFinal(text);
  }
```

After a bit more testing I discovered that the data isn't send properly by my raspberry Pi, so I'm trying to send it in blocks now.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your Encryption

Comment: I am using 'Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding' for Encryption, the encryption itself happens via the Ciper class provided by java with no additions. It just seems that Android sets everything after the given position to zero.

Comment: What is `in`, what does `read()` do? There is no allocation happening in `in.read()` the buffer is already allocated at this stage.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. In is an InputStream and my class wraps around it for encryption. You are right about the allocation, that happens when the array is initialized.

Comment: why don't you attach the code of EncryptionUtil.decrypt

Comment: I wrote myself a desktopclient and it had the same exception as the android client. It looks like the Pi does something wrong or I have to break down my array to smaller ones. But thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that the call to `in.read` hasn't read the entire input stream. `InputStream.read` isn't guaranteed to read the entire length you've requested. It's fairly normal practise to read the input stream in a while loop, reading into a buffer until the end of the stream is reached - more like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;

while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Note that your existing code doesn't check the return value from `in.read` to see how many bytes were actually read.

Comment: It did so far but I learned that nothing is really safe in networking so you are right. I did a bit more testing and saw that the problem is actually the server and I'm now going to break down the array to smaller ones. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Considering your edit I printed myself the length of bytes actually read and it matches the position after which the array only consists of zeros. My guess would be that the Pi's TCP buffer isn't large enough to contain 2 mb of data at once (but I'd highly doubt that)

Comment: You were right. My Raspberry sends the data somewhat in chunks thus I read only the first chunk.
To fix this I had 2 options: either read till my wanted size is met or use another stream provided by java which does that for me. I wrapped my bytes in an ObjectStream and used that to transfer them.